# Как применить hover эффект ко всему блоку?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как применить hover эффект, чтобы при наведении мышью на любую часть блока, менялись два изображения и цвет заголовка? Заранее огромное спасибо всем!
Часть кода:

```
<div class="col-3">
 <div class="services-card">
  <img src="img/services/icon-2.png" alt="Development" class="card-img-top">
  <div class="card-body">
   <h4 class="card-title">Development</h4>
   <p class="card-txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet.</p>
   <img src="img/services/line.png" alt="line" class="card-img-bottom">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

изменить не фоновое изображение без js не получится.

Пример на Jquery:

```
$('.col-3').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find('.services-card>img').attr('src','Новый_первый_img');
    $(this).find('.card-body>img').attr('src','Новый_второй_img');
    $(this).find('.card-body>h4').css('color','Новый_цвет_h4');
});
$('.col-3').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find('.services-card>img').attr('src','Старый_первый_img');
    $(this).find('.card-body>img').attr('src','Старый_второй_img');
    $(this).find('.card-body>h4').css('color','Старый_цвет_h4');
});
```

Но цвет заголовка можно и через css сменить:

```
.col-3:hover h4 {
    color: цвет_при_наведении;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Всё получилось!!!)))